# Error when having two HERE-DOCUMENTS in a list, how to resolve

Tags: ruby

I found I get an error when I have two HERE-DOCUMENTS inside one list. I'd like to ask how to resolve this. Here is a MWE

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w
$data=[
<<'EOT'        
more text
EOT
        ,
<<'EOT'        
and more
EOT
]
puts $data
```

The error is

```
>./t9.rb 
./t9.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'
        ,
         ^
./t9.rb:7: warning: possibly useless use of a literal in void context
./t9.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting end-of-input
```

When using `%q{` instead of `EOT` the error goes away (even though I would have expected the semantics to be the same as above example):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w
$data=[
%q{more text},
%q{and more}
]
puts $data
```

And using `EOT` in separate list entries works (i.e. list of lists)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w
$data=[[
<<'EOT'
more text
EOT
      ],
      [
<<'EOT'
and more
EOT
      ]]

puts $data
```

No error.

So the problem is *only* where more than one `EOT` is inside the same list entry. Why does this cause a problem?

```
>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [i686-linux]
```

When trying these example, make sure the `EOT` is flushed all the way to the let and that there is no spaces after it on the same line.

**Update**

For reference, the syntax I used in first example above works in perl

```
>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for 
i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
```

The script is

```
>cat t10.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = (
<<'EOT'
first line
EOT
     ,
<<'EOT'
second line
EOT
);

print @data
```

Running it

```
>./t10.pl 
first line
second line
>
```

So it works with Perl, that is why I expected it to work in Ruby.

Comment: Well, Perl is a different language than Ruby, the fact that it works in Perl means exactly nothing. There are plenty of things which work in plenty of languages which don't work in Ruby. For example, in Smalltalk, an array literal is written like this `#(1 2 3 4)`, but that won't work in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = [
<<'EOT1', <<'EOT2'
more text
EOT1
and more
EOT2
]
```

Your heredoc markers are simply in the wrong place.

Comment: The syntax I used is actually valid, at least for Perl it was. Hence I assumed it will work with Ruby. What you show is just one other way to do it, but it should have worked as well as I showed and I do not see why it did not. I'll update my question showing the Perl code.

Comment: @Nasser: Ruby just doesn't like the newline before the comma unlike Perl (in general, so this isn't some special case for arrays). You could also write it like this: https://eval.in/private/4a9bda6aef9b5a

Comment: @Nasser: No, see the program output.  Maybe you didn't spot the comma, did you? Yes, it likely looks weird but its placement is necessary in Ruby (because of the newline) however it also works in Perl: https://eval.in/private/5a9491a129a3bc

Comment: @cremno sorry, I overlooked at the output, I was just looking at code (too many things on my screen). Yes, it works! Why not post this as answer and I will upvote it also. thanks. (it is little strange that it worked without "," in the middle, but may be this is Ruby's way)